# Closure of orbit in complex manifold

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $G$ be a complex algebraic group (reductive if necessary) acting holomorphically on a complex manifold $X$. Does the closure of every $G$-orbit contain a closed orbit?

If $X$ is a complex algebraic variety and $G$ acts algebraically, this is a standard result (see [1] Proposition 1.8).

[1] A. Borel, *Linear Algebraic Groups*, Second edition. Graduate Texts in Mathematics, 126. Springer-Verlag, New York, 1991.

Answer (score 2):

No. Take a holomorphic translation vector field on the complex torus, whose orbits are translates of the dense image of some generic complex 1-dimensional linear subspace. The flow is complete, by compactness, and the group is $G=\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: That's a non-reductive example.